# Google Sheets + Apps Script: auto sending email within date parameters

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for help writing an APPS SCRIPT for a GOOGLESHEET.  I want to send out automatic reminder emails so important dates are not missed within my organization.  Let's use employee performance evaluations as an example.

I need to auto send an email to the employee's supervisor reminding them that a performance evaluation is due.

I have three columns in my spreadsheet: A-supervisor's email address, B-is a note that says whose evaluation is due and who it is assigned to, and C-the evaluation date.

I want the email to go out 2 weeks before the DATE (column C); and to be sent to the EMAIL (column A); and to have the notation of the COMMENTS (column b) in the mail body.

A       B               C
Email   Comments    Date

I tried copying/pasting other websites information but I am having trouble modifying it to specifically what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Email for Notifications:

```
function sendOutNotifications() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() - 14);
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (r[3] != "Sent" && new Date(r[2]).valueOf() < dtv) {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(r[0], "Evaluations Due", r[1]);
      sh.getRange(i + 1, 4).setValue("Sent");
    }
  });
}
```

| Email | Note | Date | Sent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |